A cursor locks a file but doesn't release it (AS/400 COBOL + DB2)
I have a program that uses a table both in a SQL cursor and as a file (READing and WRITE-ing it).
Now, every time the program runs a OPEN CURSOR that uses the table, I see in WRKOBJLCK that another lock is put on the table. But when the cursor is CLOSEd, the lock remains.
Why? And what do I do to release the lock?

Without seeing your actual DECLARE CURSOR, OPEN CURSOR, AND FETCH CURSOR statements, all we can do is guess.  What's the ISOLATION LEVEL of your DB2 database?

Does this answer your question? Why is *SHRRD lock HELD on a PF by job QZDASOINIT user QUSER, even after querying a new PF?
